# Data-toggle not working before any of the elements in the page is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular-ui-bootstrap

The setting button - datatoggle is not changing , aria-expanded ='False' by default.

When any of the elements in the page is clicked, the aria-epxanded value changes from False to True.
But before that this button does not work.

Any help ?

```
<div class="pull-right dropdown">

                                <a style="padding-left: 10px;" href="#" data-target="#"
                                    data-toggle="dropdown" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Settings">
                                    <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop4">
                                    <li><a href="#" class='js-download-csv-data'
                                        data-action='this_request&requestid=<?=$requestID?>'><i
                                            class="fa fa-download"></i> Download This Request</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="js-copy-this-request"><i
                                            class="fa fa-files-o"></i> Copy This Request</a></li>

                                    <li><a href="#" class="js-delete-this-request"><i
                                            class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw"></i> Delete This Request</a></li>

                                </ul>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have two "data-toggle" attributes within the first anchor and keep both, you're basically over-riding one of them, or the latter one might get ignore.